# Combine all JSON files in a particular folder

Tags: ruby, jruby

I have a folder with a number of JSON files within it.

I want to take all `.json` files, where the filename ends with `_LAST.json`, and combine them into one JSON file. Each of the files that are to be processed are named like:

```
Bill_LAST.json
Jane_LAST.json
Kitty_LAST.json
```

`Bill_LAST.json` looks like:

```
[{

    "Date": "2012-11-19",
    "Name": "Bill",
    "Age": 54,
    "Sex": "M"

}]
```

Comment: Sounds fun.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be as simple as:

```
json = Dir['./*_LAST.json'].map { |f| JSON.parse File.read(f) }.flatten
```

#### [Here](http://cibox.org/slivu/stackoverflow?path=is-there-an-easy-way-of-combining-two-json-files-or-splitting-one-json-in-ruby&lang=ruby&file=last.rb&run=true) is a working demo.

Comment: `Dir['./*_LAST.json'].map{ |f| JSON.parse File.read(f) }` +1 You could just `map` the collection instead of using `inject`.

Comment: @Kyle Your answer reads from the file and parses the data, but then throws them all away immediately.

Comment: @banzaiman My answer does exactly the same thing that the accepted answer does. The only difference is that I left off the assignment to save space. `json = Dir['./*_LAST.json'].map{ |f| JSON.parse File.read(f) }`

Comment: @Kyle, you right, thank you, not sure how i ended in using `inject`. updating answer. @user1644609, please consider to use shorter version